# How to explode without losing null values?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

How can I explode an array in U-SQL without losing the Null values?

In normal Cross Apply | Explode(), Null values are lost.

I extracted the following script from [here](https://vincentlauzon.com/2016/01/10/u-sql-cross-apply/):

```
@content =
        SELECT *
        FROM(
            VALUES
            (
                12,
                "a, b, c,NULL"
            ),
            (  75,
                "f, g, h, i, j"
            )) AS t([ID], LetterList);         
    @inArray =
        SELECT [ID],
            SqlArray.Create(LetterList.Split(',')) AS LetterArray
        FROM @content;         
    @exploded =
        SELECT [ID],
            letter.Trim() AS Letter
        FROM @inArray
        CROSS APPLY
        EXPLODE(LetterArray) AS r(letter);         
    OUTPUT @exploded
    TO "/Outputs/explosion.tsv"
    USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

The output I'm expecting is:

ID - Letter 
------------ 
12 - a 
12 - b 
12 - c 
12 - NULL 
75 - f 
75 - g 
75 - h 
75 - i 
75 - j

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`OUTER APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/select-selecting-from-cross-apply-and-outer-apply):

> When OUTER APPLY is specified, **one row is produced for each row of the left rowset even when the right-side rowset expression returns an empty rowset for that row**.

```
@exploded =
        SELECT [ID],
            letter.Trim() AS Letter
        FROM @inArray
        OUTER APPLY
        EXPLODE(LetterArray) AS r(letter);
```